# ValueError: vector too long when loading .bin model fasttext in jupyter notebook Windows

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, fasttext

I just want to reduce the dimension of this embedding to 100, and I need to load the model however when I load it error happens

my code

```
import fasttext
import fasttext.util
ft = fasttext.load_model('indo.bin')
```

The error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3faff30dc420> in <module>
----> 1 ft = fasttext.load_model('indo.bin')

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fasttext\FastText.py in load_model(path)
    434 def load_model(path):
    435     """Load a model given a filepath and return a model object."""
--> 436     return _FastText(model_path=path)
    437 
    438 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fasttext\FastText.py in __init__(self, model_path, args)
     92         self.f = fasttext.fasttext()
     93         if model_path is not None:
---> 94             self.f.loadModel(model_path)
     95         self._words = None
     96         self._labels = None

ValueError: vector too long
```

Does anyone know why this happens? when I load it in colab nothing's wrong. However, when I load it in my local computer it returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on one system, but not another, the most interesting things to investigate are differences between those two systems. Are they running the same Python version, and exact same supporting libraries?

Most significantly, if you're using the official Facebook Fasttext code & Python package, I don't see any statement that it's supported on Windows OSes:

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText#requirements

Looking at issues in their Github repository, there are a lot of open issues with problems installing/building on Windows, with only a few hints that some people have made it work using unofficial extra steps or Python "Wheels" from non-official sources. You may want to use a Linux OS locally, in a virtual machine if necessary, to have the easiest time with this package (and others in the Python ML/text-learning stack that generally get more development/testing/use on non-Windows systems).